# Facebook login name format

Tags: c#, facebook

Hi i have a facebook login code and im trying to change the format of the name to Firstname-Lastname is there a way to do this? My code is below

I cannot include all of my code because it is very long

```
//Example: Say my name on fb was... Josh Smith
//$_SESSION['user']['username'] = "Josh-Smith";

//Code
$user_info = $facebook->api('/me/');
$_SESSION['user']['username'] = $user_info['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Code
$user_info = $facebook->api('/me/');
$_SESSION['user']['username'] = $user_info['first_name'] . '-' . $user_info['last_name'];
```